# Unable to pass the JobParameters Value to the tasklet in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I already followed link: [Pass JobParameters and ExecutionContext to @Bean Tasklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803657/pass-jobparameters-and-executioncontext-to-bean-tasklet), but still facing issue while passing the `jobParameters` value to the `tasklet`.

I've developed a code like below:

JobConfiguration.java

```
@Component
public class JobConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name) {
        System.out.println("NAME VALUE  = "+name);
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("The job run for %s", name));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet(null))
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

JobLaunchingController.java

```
@RestController
public class JobLaunchingController {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @PostMapping("/")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void launch(@RequestParam("name") String name) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("name", name)
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("STATUS = "+jobExecution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2018-12-13 23:09:35.930  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-13 23:09:35.930  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-13 23:09:35.938  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2018-12-13 23:09:55.046  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{name=foo}]
2018-12-13 23:09:55.414  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
The job run for null
2018-12-13 23:09:55.672  INFO 20004 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{name=foo}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
STATUS = COMPLETED
```

StartingAJobApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class StartingAJobApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartingAJobApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

CURL:

> curl --data 'name=foo' localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's normal because you are passing the tasklet to the job yourself and it has null param.

in order to use @StepScop feature, you need to use the bean spring created

```
    @Bean
    public Job job(Tasklet tasklet) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: the bean is stepscoped so it's creation won't be the same as calling the function only, have you tested the solution I provided you

Answer (score 0):

When you implement “execute” method, you have SetpContribution and ChunkContext as parameters. You have to use ChunkContext to get jobParameter.

```
  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    JobParameters jobParameters = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobParameters();

      ...
}
```